# Supabase: Allow all user to insert but not to select

Tags: postgresql, supabase

I set up a subscription form to allow customers to subscribe to my coming soon page while waiting to build the MVP.
I'm using Supabase to store the customer's email and name.
For security purposes, I need to set up the row level security.
The thing is that I want to allow only for people to INSERT but not to delete, read and update the data.
This is what I did but if a user doesn't have the possibility to select, he doesn't have the possibility to insert.
How can I make in sort to allow an anonymous user to INSERT but not to SELECT, DELETE or UPDATE?
I don't want someone to find the database and be able to fetch all the data.

Comment: Allowing a PostgreSQL user to insert but not select is trivial. If you tried that and failed, then you did something wrong.  But we don't know what it was you did wrong, because you failed to give us any useful information.  What did you do? What error did you get?

Comment: A Postgresql database is made the way that you need to add row-level security. I added the possibility to INSERT which is working well if there is a row-level security that allows to READ. If I remove it, I have an error. The challenge here is that I'm using Supabase so the API is public. It will be easier with a custom backend but I can't for now. That's the reason why I'm looking for a workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow users to insert without giving them the possibility to anybody to fetch the data, you need to set the "Row security level" to INSERT for anon.

```
CREATE POLICY "Allow user to insert" ON "public"."email_lst"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR INSERT
TO anon
USING (true)
```

Then you need to add the insert function into your code but without the select at the end because select is returning the created record. I commented here to show.

```
const { data, error } = await _supabase
    .from('email_lst')
    .insert([ { first_name: first, last_name: last, email, remark }])
    // .select();
```

Comment: That policy is allowing all users to select all rows.

Comment: @Bergi my bad, I have updated it

Comment: @AnthoVdo ERROR:  only WITH CHECK expression allowed for INSERT

Comment: @fractal are you sure that you don't use an old Supabase version or something? Because "Using" has been fixed since September and as you can see in my example, I can use it.